# Cannot install plugins on Centos VPS

Tags: plugins

I am unable to install plugins on my Centos 6 VPS. When I attempt the install I get this:

> Installing Plugin: BotDetect WordPress CAPTCHA 3.0.Beta1.7
>
> Downloading install package from 
>   [web path to:]botdetect-wp-captcha.zip…
>   Unpacking the package…
>   Could not create directory.
>   Return to Plugin Installer

UPDATE: This seems to have something to do with permissions -- I'm guessing there's some group that wordpress needs to be part of in order to change folders, create files, etc., but I can't figure out what that group should be. I have no www-data group -- I read something somewhere about this being a requirement. Can somebody tell me what groups and permissions need to exist for WP to operate?

UPDATE: I have chmodded the permissions to my plugin and uploads folders to 777. I also have created an FTP user specifically for Wordpress and made the home directory for that user the same as my Wordpress root folder as recommended [HERE](http://blog.noizeramp.com/2008/09/10/wordpress-unable-to-locate-wordpress-plugin-directory/). I then changed these lines in the wp-config.php file from:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__ . "/"));

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

to:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__));

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-settings.php');
```

This should eliminate the double slash conflict mentioned [HERE](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/abspath-question).

Note -- I was also having a problem uploading media but that issues was resolved with the chmod to 777.

Now when I try to install a plugin I get this:

```
Unable to locate WordPress Plugin directory.

Return to Plugin Installer
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured this out based upon suggestions from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673184/wordpress-fails-to-install-plugins-unable-to-locate-wordpress-plugin-directory). This is how I resolved this issue:

```
I created a group called ftpusers.

groupadd ftpusers

I added my wordpress user to this group.

usermod -a -G ftpusers wordpressuser

I changed ownership of the wordpress folder recursively to my wordpress user:group.

chown -R wordpressuser:ftpusers wordpress
```

Voila -- my package installed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't seem to be regarding CentOS but the permissions of your folders. Try creating the plugins folder in your wp-content. If that doesn't work try CHMODDING 755 or 777 (though this may be risky, try just for testing purposes) on the newly creating plugins folder.

Comment: I had already created the plugins folder under wp-content and it was 755. I changed it to 777 and still the same problem. I tried using an alternate FTP user/pw combo and got this:

Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content).

Return to Plugin Installer

Comment: I had this problem a while ago. I tried a fresh install of WP and everything had been fixed. You may want to wait for another answer.

Comment: Actually, it is a fresh install. I just added wordpress to my site.